# Execute code once per day

Tags: php, apache

I have entries in my database which has an expiration date. I would like to clean the database by removing those entries once they expired once every day.

Is there anyway to execute a php script (who does this job) at a specific time, say 00:00 every day? Or is there any different approach which is better?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+cron+job

Comment: What platform/OS is your server?

Comment: im using a linux server! not sure if i have access to cron jobs tho :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what kind of server you are using, but you can configure `Cron Jobs` on Linux to achieve that. Most live Apache servers run on Linux anyway, so this is what you would probably need to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs are exactly made for that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

If you're using cPanel, you may create them directly from your control panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to crontab on the server, I'd suggest an alternative like: http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/

Otherwise, `crontab` or `at` will suit your needs.